# Kotlin Current Function Name by Anonymous Object No Longer Works in Kotlin 1.3.x

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin JVM 1.2.x, I use to be able to do the following:

```
inline fun <R> Logger.logStuff(
    crossinline f: () -> R
): R {
    val methodName = object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
    try {
        this.debug("$methodName : Begin")
        f()
        this.debug("$methodName : End")
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        this.error("$methodName : Threw exception : $ex")
        throw ex
    }
}

class Foo {
    fun doStuff() = log.logStuff {
        1 + 3
    }
}
```

This would give me logs like:

```
Foo : doStuff : Begin
Foo : doStuff : End
```

But, after upgrading to Kotlin 1.3.50 (from 1.2.x), I got logs like the following:

```
Foo : logStuff : Begin
Foo : logStuff : End
```

I am aware of `currentThread().stackTrace[1].methodName` to get the enclosing method name, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Is there another way to get the current function name?

Answer (score 2):

You may convert your logStuff() fun to extension and make your R type reified, like this:

```
inline fun <reified R : Any> R.logStuff() {
    val methodName = object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
}
```

**Update 08/12/22:**

What is the difference and what this solution gives us?

We may improve it just a little bit more to visualise it better:

```
inline fun <reified R : Any> R?.log(msg: String?) = this?.run {
    val objectId: String = this::class.simpleName ?: this::class.hashCode().toString()
    val methodName = object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod?.name
    Log.d("TAG", "$objectId.$methodName() {\n  $msg\n}")
}
```

Now we may use it just like:

```
class ExampleClass {
    fun exampleFun() {
        log("test")
    }
}
```

And it will give us an output like:

```
ExampleClass.exampleFun() {
  test
}
```

Because log function is inlined, the code will be executed inside an "exampleFun()".

As you may see, there would be a "Current Function Name" in the output. Please also note, that in some cases class may not have a simpleName, that's why there is a fallback to hashCode.

**Update 30/01/22:**

If above doesn't work for you, please try this:

```
inline fun <reified R : Any> R?.log(msg: String?) = this?.run {
    val objectId: String = this::class.simpleName ?: this::class.hashCode().toString()
    val methodName = StackWalker.getInstance().walk { frames ->
        frames.findFirst().map { it.methodName }.orElse(null)
    }
    println("$objectId.$methodName() {\n  $msg\n}")
}
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example of your idea? I am confused since in my case, R is the result of the lambda.

Comment: That was a complete example of how similar fun works in my case.

Comment: In my case logStuff is an extension function which is copied to the calling function by a compiler and calling function becomes an enclosingMethod, but in your case logStuff is a part of Logger class.

Comment: I don’t think that is going yo work in my case because I need to wrap the execution of a lambda.

Comment: This seems to be just a complicate way to wrote "logStuff".

Comment: You're right, after all this time I have hard times understanding what I was trying to say myself. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: no working for 1.7.x

Comment: Added another update, tested on playground: https://shorturl.at/AEKQ2